# Get all the layers in a packet

Tags: python, scapy

How can I get a list of all the layers in scapy?
Eg: `Ether/IP/UDP/DNS` or `Ether/IP/TCP/HTTP`.
The only thing I can think of is to do a `packet.summary()` and parse the output, which seems very crude. I think there should be a method built-in, but cannot find any in the documentation. Any suggestions?

What I am trying to do is to iterate over all the fields of a specific protocol given by a user and display its values.

Update:
What I am looking for exactly can be seen in wireshark: Open any capture, select a packet, and in the 'Frame' menu, one can see
`Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:data`
This is exactly what I am looking for in Scapy. I hope I am clearer now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `packet.getLayer(<id>)` in a loop. For example:

```
from scapy.all import Ether

def get_packet_layers(packet):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        layer = packet.getlayer(counter)
        if layer is None:
            break

        yield layer
        counter += 1


packet = 'ffffffffffff00ffd59c64320806000108000604000100ffd59c6432000000000000000000000a000001'.decode('hex')
packet = Ether(_pkt=packet)

for layer in get_packet_layers(packet):
    print (layer.name)
```

outputs

```
Ethernet
ARP
```

Comment: Output:
    `Layers are:  ['Ethernet', 'IP', 'TCP']`

Answer (score 11):

Each additional layer is the payload of a packet, so you can iterate

```
def expand(x):
    yield x
    while x.payload:
        x = x.payload
        yield x
```

and then

```
res = list(expand(packet))
```

I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: This doesn't give me the layers in the packet. It just prints the packet contents. What I am looking for exactly can be seen in wireshark: Open any capture, select a packet, and in the 'Frame' menu, one can see `Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:data`. This is exactly what I am looking for in Scapy. I hope I am clearer now.

Comment: It does, just each packet contains all upper layers by construction. See @eminor who prints the names with my method.

Answer (score 5):

I looked at the [source code](http://hg.secdev.org/scapy/file/7621f33286b9/scapy/packet.py) and didn't find such a method, so I altered cronos's code a bit and it looks like it does what you want now.

You could write a bug report for scapy and suggest a new method.

```
>>> ip = Ether()/IP()/TCP()
>>> ip
<Ether  type=0x800 |<IP  frag=0 proto=tcp |<TCP  |>>>
>>> ip.name
'Ethernet'
>>> def expand(x):
...     yield x.name
...     while x.payload:
...         x = x.payload
...         yield x.name
... 
>>> list(expand(ip))
['Ethernet', 'IP', 'TCP']
>>> l=list(expand(ip))
>>> ":".join(l)
'Ethernet:IP:TCP'
>>>
```

Comment: I was trying something similar when you answered this and logged in to post my answer! Check my code below.

Answer (score 2):

With `packet.payload.layers()` i get a list of layer classes for the packet. I can then access the packet layers, for example:

```
def sniff_callback(packet):
    print(packet.payload.layers())  # display all layers
    first_layer = packet[packet.payload.layers()[0]]  # access first layer of the list
```

Comment: The Ethernet layer don't show in the list, any idea please ?