# Python Import issues: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'

Tags: python, linux, scapy, xbmc

I'm trying to write a little python script on Linux Embedded with scapy lib. 
On my OsX or Linux box i don't have any problem to do something like this:

```
from scapy.all import IP, sniff
from scapy.layers import http
import urllib, re

def process_tcp_packet(packet):

    http_layer = packet.getlayer(http.HTTPRequest)
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    url = str('{1[Path]}'.format(ip_layer.fields, http_layer.fields))
    if url:
        url = urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
        print re.findall(r'(https?://\S+lh1)', url)


sniff(filter="tcp and host hostexample.com", prn=process_tcp_packet)
```

The Scapy folder looks like this:

```
enter code here
/scapy
  __init__.py
  all.py
  ...
  /layers
   __init__.py
   http.py
   dhcp.py
   ...
```

When i start the script, it seems that all modules are imported but the line:

```
url = str('{1[Path]}'.format(ip_layer.fields, http_layer.fields))
```

Return the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'
-->End of Python script error report<--
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you printed `http_layer` to see what it actually returns?

Comment: Could be more useful to print `packet` and see what is being passed in. `getlayer` seems to be returning None.

Comment: When I look at various scappy example, they always seem to include an identifier in getlayer. Look at the answer at the end of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549294/get-all-the-layers-in-a-packet

Comment: To debug your application, start by printing all the layers to the console; you might realize there aren't any layers, and that's why getlayer() is returning None. If there are layers, it's because you must specify which one you want (or find a way to iterate through them)

Answer (score 0):

"print http_layer" on the OsX-Box:

```
GET
PATH: someurl....
Http-Version: HTTP/1.1
Host: hostexample.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:37.0)    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://hostexample/someurl
Connection: keep-alive
```

on Embedded: "None"

Comment: I believe that the Embedded System doesn't start to sniff..so packet is empty and also http_layer.